# merge commit has been pushed on the two source branchs

Tags: git

Something strange happened to the project.

- We had a branch "source" from which we created a branch "feature".
- we checkout the branch "feature" and create 3 files.
- then we realize something is missing on branch "source". So We go back on it and edit another file. Since the new added files are not tracked by git, they are still in the project, but we don't commit them. we edit another file that we commit.
- we go back to "feature" and merge the "source" into feature and we push. the feature is created on the remote.

What we don't understand, is that the initial commit, the one with the three files is now in the "source" branch too.

git reflog of all pushes to source

```
C:\path>git reflog show awsOrigin/source
  31325f0ea (awsOrigin/source) refs/remotes/awsOrigin/source@{0}: push: forced-update
  1921667a4 (source) refs/remotes/awsOrigin/source@{1}: push: forced-update
  8738f3c91 refs/remotes/awsOrigin/source@{2}: fetch: forced-update
  9c89b3654 refs/remotes/awsOrigin/source@{3}: fetch: forced-update
```

the commit 31325f0ea is the commit when we merge source into feature. I don't understand why it has been pushed on remote source. The commit 1921667a4 is the one we made to change just one file.

Git reflog of the "three files commit" shows 3 branches : awsOrigin/source, awsOrigin/feature and local feature

What could have happened ? 
We use the Git perspective of Eclipse to make commits and pushes

--- EDIT

here is a graphic representation of what happend
[image]
"init properties" is the "three files commit"
"passage version 10.0.0" is the one with one change on a certain file, the one that was made in source

git log --graph --oneline awsOrigin/source
[image: git log --graph --oneline awsOrigin/source]

Comment: Something that stands out from those logs is that all your fetches and pushes are *forced*. That should only be necessary if you're rewriting history (amending commits or rebasing) and may mean some useful sanity checks were skipped during those pushes and pulls.

Comment: yes, i know, but that's how Eclipse works, it's totally stupid but for now we have no choice but use it

Comment: Fair enough, I've not used that client / plugin. Maybe there's some other dodgy defaults it's using which have caused your problem.

Comment: I had plenty problems with that (the line ending problem got me crazy, eclipse doesn't take the autocrlf configuration if it's outside of the project). I was wondering what could have made Eclipse to lead to the "three files commit" on the source branch

Comment: Are you really forced to use the git functionality of Eclipse? That thing really does not cut it for me. Maybe try Gitkraken. No need to change anything in your repos, just install and use it and never touch any git function in Eclipse again.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide git log --graph -- oneline or something similar. It's hard to follow.

Comment: actually it's not me, my colleagues absolutely want to use Eclipse. It was already a big trouble just to convince them to change from cvs to git, the less I change their habits, the better it is for now. later i'll convince them to change from eclipse to intellij, but until then, I am stuck with eclipse

Comment: Sorry to hear that. The way your reflog looks like, you pushed all those commits to `source`. Are you really sure `feature` was checked out before pushing? I would like to see that `git log --graph --oneline` too

Comment: Actually I wasn't there to see what really happened, that's what I am trying to understand. But the person who made the manipulations don't remember having pushed anything on feature branch to source branch
@c

Comment: @Christoph I made a change where I gave a graphic representation of history

Comment: Can the person who does not remember be asked to share some logs with you? So sorry that you have to work in such a malfunctionally communicating environment.

Comment: So, to start the other way around: What do you need your history to look like? The current state seems to impose a problem, but what do you need?

Comment: ok, which logs should I give ? (the log from command line I gave is already from the colleagues' computer)
Actually there is no real problem of communication, that's just when they made this merge I wasn't there and they asked me what could have lead to this situation, maybe it's an Eclipse problem (most of my coworkers agree to the Eclipse problem, but nobody has time to really make a migration from one IDE to another, all of our environment is based on Eclipse, so if we want to change something we need to test if everything is ok, if it really worth to pass grom free ide to intellij...)

Comment: the problem is solved since we just made a revert on the source branch, for now I am just trying to know how this happened, to not having this problem again

Comment: My experience: if you have trouble with git, use git bash. Then you are sure what you do. Your picture doesn't help me.

Comment: @Christoph I made another edit with  "git log --graph --oneline awsOrigin/source"

Comment: So you mean the last commit should not be online?

Comment: "init properties" should not be on branch "source", it should be only on "feature"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the graphs you've added are cut off such that it's hard to make anything from them - the graphical one has so many labels missing there's no context of which lines are which, and the command-line one cuts off at the crucial moment when branches are merging.

However, I can see a few things on the command-line graph which don't match your description of what your colleague thought they did:

- The shared parent `8738` doesn't show on the left-hand side of the graph. On the command-line view, I would expect the purple line to be the "source" branch, but there seems to be an extra (yellow) branch coming in.
- The `e121` and `1921` commits both branch from this point. We can't tell what the branches were called at the time, because git doesn't record that.
- The `3132` commit shows "source" being merged into "feature", as described.
- However, the next commit, cut-off, is another merge commit (the cyan line going to meet the purple).
- The graphical view looks a bit different, but presumably the grey line, again cut off at the top, is this same merge.

If the grey line in the graphical view / purple line in the text view are "another feature", what ended up happening is someone merged "feature" into "another feature". If the person performing this merge thought they were pulling from "source", then presumably at that point, "source" and "feature" were *pointing at the same commit*.

What seems to have happened is that someone *reset* the "source" branch to point at that commit; possibly clicking the wrong option and thinking they were just switching branches in their checkout. This just moves the pointer, which is all a branch is in git.

Since git doesn't particularly mind whether a branch is on the left or right of a merge (for that matter, there can be more than two parents) pointing "source" at that commit is the same as performing the merge the other way around. This would have been a valid fast-forward push even if your client wasn't misconfigured to always force.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response ! the next merge from with we see 3132 divide again is someone who merged the "source" into another feature branch to get the last updates. This person now have a "bad" commit in his branch that is not supposed to be on it

Comment: Right, so at that point `source` and `feature` were presumably *pointing at the same commit*. See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, that is probably what happened